# fragment in android studio not showing dashboard on my phone

Tags: android-studio

I am creating a dashboard for a bill payments app using android studio, I am trying to run the project on my phone and the fragment where the dashboard is supposed to appear is showing a blank screen. Apparently, there is a bottom navigation tab on the fragment which I want the dashboard to appear on.

Gradle build finished successfully and the dashboard is appearing the way I want it in the design tab but its not showing anything on my phone. What might be the problem? Below is the xml file for the dashboard. I haven't started working on the `.java` code as of yet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:padding="10dp">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:padding="0dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="130dp"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="80dp"
                            android:layout_height="80dp"
                            android:contentDescription="@null"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/zetdc" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/zesa_topup"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:padding="0dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="130dp"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="80dp"
                            android:layout_height="80dp"
                            android:contentDescription="@null"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/econet" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/econet_airtime"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:padding="0dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="130dp"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="80dp"
                            android:layout_height="80dp"
                            android:contentDescription="@null"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/netone" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/netone_airtime"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:padding="0dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="130dp"
                        android:gravity="center">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="64dp"
                            android:layout_height="64dp"
                            android:contentDescription="@null"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/telecel" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/telecel_airtime"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image: this is the design mode and the dashboard is appearing well]

[image: this is on my mobile phone where nothing is appearing]

Answer (score 0):

Code is working for me

Check this

[image]